# Find O(n) solution to variation of prefix sum

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

[image: Problem]

I know that this problem is a variation of prefix-sum, i'm just having some difficulty setting it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define:

```
P[i] = A[i+1] + A[i+2] + ... + A[n]
Q[i] = A[1] + ... + A[i-1]
```

Then, `S[i] = P[i] + Q[i]`

Answer (score 2):

What about calculating two arrays: 
Lefts[i] which will be equal the sum of first i elements, :

```
Lefts[i] = A[0]+A[1]+A[2]..+A[i]
```

and Rights[i] which will be equal to the sum of the last i elements :

```
Rights[i] = A[n-1]+A[n-2]..+A[i]
```

Then `S[i] = Left[i-1]+Rigt[i+1]`.

Comment: Looks like you need minus operation or at least decrement for index calculation.

Comment: @Henrik It's possible to calculate Rights[i] without decrementing by reversing the list A. But honestly, I think decrementing is OK

Comment: @ig-melnyk I have misread the statement and I will remove my comment as it is wrong. However a solution without memory overhead can be implemented and I explain how in my answer.

Comment: @ig-melnyk I don't quite see how to reverse the array without decrementing, but you're probably right and decrementing is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The idea I propose boils down to what is already suggested in the other answers. However I want to propose an implementation with constant memory overhead:

```
initialize S with 0
for i = 2 to n {
  S[i] = S[i -1] + A[i - 1] // somewhat similar to prefix sum array
}

help = 0 // a single variable - constant memory overhead
for i = n to 1 {
  S[i] += help
  help += A[i]
}
```

After the first iteration S[i] stores the sum of all values with indices less than i. On the second iteration I add the sum of the values on the right of the current value.

Answer (score 1):

Define B[i] = A[1] + ... A[i-1] and C[i] = A[i+1] + ... + A[n] then S[i] = B[i] + C[i].

You can compute both arrays in linear time. You need to iterate backwards to compute C in linear time.

Total number of additions is 3N - 2 (one addition for each position, expect the first in B and last in C).

Comment: Can you explain how you got 3N - 2 ? Is it because B and A each take N additions and then S takes another N additions giving us 3N ? But I still don't understand the - 2

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm B[1] and C[n] are 0 so you don't need an addition for these 2.